# Issues creating new Rails app (rake 10.1.0/Bundler failure)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, railstutorial.org

When running `rails new sample_app --skip-test-unit` on ruby 2.0.0p247/Rails 4.0.0, I keep getting this after "bundle install":

```
>Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
>Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..
>Resolving dependencies...

>ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in UTF-8
>An error occurred while installing rake (10.1.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>Make sure that `gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I've tried running both `gem install rake` and the above suggestion with the same results.  Any suggestions?  Thanks.  For what its worth I'm trying to get through the Hartl Rails tutorial.

Comment: did you try `sudo gem install rake -v '10.1.0'` ?

Comment: I think `sudo gem install ...` will not fix the problem! I think the similar problem will be for any gem from your Gemfile. I posted possible solution.

Comment: Tried `sugo gem install ...` followed by `bundle install` and still getting the argument error.  My system was up 2 weeks ago and I'm not sure what changed.  I'm looking at gotva's solutions now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe this helps you http://blog.oasic.net/2012/04/solutions-to-invalid-byte-sequence-in.html
the problem is not in gems!

Comment: Declared the $LANG in the bash_profile as @gotva suggested.  Worked perfectly.